# How to organize many configs to one stylus project with webpack

Tags: stylus, webpack

I want to use a lot of style config files for a project based on Webpack. Now I'm using variable for this:

```
    loaders: [
   ...
  , { test: /\.styl$/,  loader: "style!css!postcss!stylus?paths[]=node_modules&paths[]=app&import=apps/" + appName + "/config.styl" }
    ...
```

Everything going fine, but the problem now is that the auto-update does not work when I edit the config.styl. Maybe there is a better way? Or how can I fix auto update in this case?

Comment: Can you replace that `config.styl` import bit with `@import` at your stylus entry point? I have a feeling you need to simplify your loader definition somehow as that would fix auto-update neatly.

Comment: but how to use env appName - stylus-loader allow variables in @import?

Comment: Maybe you could apply https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin? If that gets triggered before `@import` gets evaluated, that should work.

Comment: thank you! 
As I had not thought about it? This might work!

Comment: wtf (  again, all works ok, but HMR fails

Comment: One more idea. You could set up [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) for your configuration import. That would avoid having to use replace plugin. Maybe Webpack will catch that better.

Comment: Thank you! I already fix stylus-loader to watch this manual import, but how to +1 this answer too?

Comment: I moved the ideas to an answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: if you want to get postcss work with stylus, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006607/getting-started-with-stylus-loader-for-webpack?s=2|1.8139

Comment: How did you get the string-replace-plugin working? Mine failed because it couldn't process the stylus file with the placeholder in it. Is there any way I can make sure the placeholder gets replaced before that?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas to try out (migrated from comments):

- [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) could be used to generate imports dynamically - Unfortunately it looks like HMR doesn't pick it up. You can try invoking it as a [preLoader](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-preloaders-module-postloaders)
- Set up [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) for configuration. This avoids having to use replace plugin and feels like a cleaner alternative.