# Getting Started With stylus-loader for Webpack

Tags: webpack

Alright so (new to this):

I  just added my `stylus-loader`, `style-loader` (as recommended by `stylus-loader`) and the loader `{ test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader' }` to the webpack config. Now on my Main.js file I'm adding `var css = require('!css!stylus!./Main.styl');`. So, should I be seeing the compiled css in the html now ? Not sure if I'm getting this right.

**webpack.config.js**

```
webpackConfig = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        app: ['webpack/hot/dev-server','./index.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
            { test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader' }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

**index.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var Main = require('./App/Components/Main');

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Main />
        )
    }   
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

**Main.js**

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react';
import ReactCanvas from 'react-canvas';
var css = require('!css!stylus!./Main.styl'); 

var {
    Surface
} = ReactCanvas;

class Main extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.size = document.getElementById('main').getBoundingClientRect() 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Surface top={0} left={0} width={this.size.width} height={this.size.height}>
            </Surface>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = Main
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>


    <header>
        <h1>React Canvas</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="main"></div>

    <script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace

```
var css = require('!css!stylus!./Main.styl');
```

with

```
var css = require('./Main.styl');
```

thanks to your setup.

The CSS will get converted into JavaScript and included in the JavaScript bundle by default.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

check my config

https://github.com/crapthings/postcss-test

https://github.com/crapthings/postcss-test/blob/master/webpack.config.js

```
var poststylus = require('poststylus')

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015'], plugins: ['add-module-exports'] } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css!postcss', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style!css!stylus', exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    },
    stylus: {
        use: [poststylus(['autoprefixer', 'postcss-short', 'postcss-sorting', 'postcss-cssnext', 'rucksack-css'])]
    }
}
```

https://github.com/crapthings/postcss-test/blob/master/app/index.js

```
require('style!./test.styl')
```

i can get stylus and postcss work with inline style

but i can't figure out how to make a bundle.css to

```
<link rel=stylesheet />
```

Comment: Copy and pasting code is bad: you misspell `exclude` everywhere you write it.

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled "exclude" with "exculde".

And btw (https://github.com/seaneking/poststylus):

"Unfortunately the Stylus end event that PostStylus uses to pass back post-processed css doesn't accept a callback, so until this bug is patched upstream PostStylus cannot work with asynchronous PostCSS processing."

I had to make separate files for using LostCSS (PostCSS grid) which I imported with just the grid (each component had it's own style.styl file and lost.css file). Worked for me.