# How to programmatically render a stylus folder?

Tags: node.js, stylus

I want to programmatically do the following (located in package.json - essentially, renders the .styl documents in the "assets" folder and saves them as CSS files)

```
    "scripts": {
     "stylus": "stylus assets --compress"
    }
```

Currently I do the following:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process'


await exec('npm run stylus')
```

While this does work, I want to know if there is a better way of doing this, and I want it so that I can execute this multiple times later on in the code, as it isn't necessarily for pre-rendering

Comment: While doing a bit of background work, I realised that Gulp supported Stylus (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-stylus) therefore, I'm looking at the possibility of using Gulp.

Comment: Confirmed that the process can be ran through gulp via gulp-stylus, however cannot confirm it can be ran multiple times programmatically, still testing.

Comment: Testing the following method with webpack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006607/getting-started-with-stylus-loader-for-webpack